# UITextView: Selecting only highlights top half of the text

Tags: ios, uitextview

[image: Problem Illustration]

Does anybody know why this is happening? Let me know if you need more information other than what's captured in the screenshot.

Thanks!

Comment: Test it on a phone, these sort of things occur in the simulator since xcode 6.

Comment: Tested on a phone - iphone 6. Same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text view doesn't have enough height for material it needs to display. Make it taller. Also, look for other things you may be doing that cause it to lose height when the view loads.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, matt. What you see is what you get here. I created a new project without a single line of added code.

Comment: He means resize your textview. It looks like you have made the height almost minimum.